# Webscraping walmarts products with puppeteer on google compute platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

I try to use puppeteer on the Google Cloud Platform (VM Instance).
The code works ok on my local machine. But when I run it on GCP I always get the forbidden response with the request.
Is there any configuration I need to set on GCP?

example.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
        ],
    });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://walmart.com');
        const bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
        console.log(bodyHTML);
        await browser.close();
})();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "example.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

run example.js

```
node example.js 
Forbidden
1587058087-94-320-69028280
```

if I change to parse www.target.com, it works ok.

Comment: **1**. Update your question with full text of the error **2**. Try to execute it in command line and provide full output and update your question with it **3**. Which Cloud API access scopes are enabled for your VM? **4**. In which way and where are you going to save results of webscaping?

Comment: I rewrite to a simple example. The error message shows that "Forbidden". I don't use any Cloud API now. Just want to try the puppeteer on the Google Cloud Platform

Comment: Thank you. It looks like your problem caused by some limitations at `walmart.com` and have no connections to GCP. Do you have the same error when you run it locally?

Comment: There is no problem when I run it locally. And I also try change the url to "www.amazon.com". It had the same "Forbidden" message. But when I try to parse target, it works ok.

Comment: Do you have any Firewall rule or Load Balancer in your project? Also, where is the instance located? I ask these questions since the fact that you can contact 'target' but not 'walmart' makes it seem like a network issue.

Comment: It locates us-west1-b. I don't use any load balancer. And with you advice, I enable all the port for my firewall. It still have the same message. If I try to access a image from walmart. ex: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/96e69681-ff79-412c-9a1a-687591587d17_1.82b
2ba02bdb093a8f032147251eb56a7.jpeg. It can work. But if I access walmart.com or walmart.com/index.html, it doesn't work. Is that some kind of redirection from the walmart site cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "UserAgent" need to be set. For example,

```
page.setUserAgent(
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
                );
```

then it works. Thanks for everyone's help.